# Deploy to EKS using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy k8s deployment(simple pod) to EKS.
I am using Jenkins 2.319.1 and all plugins up to date and using Kubernetes cd plugin.
I have an error that user system:anonymous cannot patch resource "pods" in API group in the namespace default. I am not sure what is the reason? I seared a lot, but didn't solve yet. Could someone help me

```
Starting Kubernetes deployment
Loading configuration: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/eks/nginx.yaml
ERROR: ERROR: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://0615cdb22445853e01165ad9c054a48f.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: Forbidden! User arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:705746146520:cluster/my-eks-last doesn't have permission. pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: POST at: https://0615cdb22445853e01165ad9c054a48f.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods. Message: Forbidden! User arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:705746146520:cluster/my-eks-last doesn't have permission. pods is forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot create resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default".
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.requestFailure(OperationSupport.java:472)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.assertResponseCode(OperationSupport.java:409)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:381)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleCreate(OperationSupport.java:227)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleCreate(BaseOperation.java:780)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.create(BaseOperation.java:349)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$PodUpdater.createResource(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:806)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$PodUpdater.createResource(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:775)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$ResourceUpdater.createOrApply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:377)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper.apply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.doCall(DeploymentCommand.java:168)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:105)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1259)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:67)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:46)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeploy.perform(KubernetesDeploy.java:42)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:54)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.SimpleBuildStepExecution.run(SimpleBuildStepExecution.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: It means that you didn't authenticate to the cluster and the cluster doesn't allow anonymous user to create resources.

Answer (score 0):

`...POST at: https://0615cdb22445853e01165ad9c054a48f.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods...`

You didn't setup the plugin credential correctly, as a result your job is making direct call to the cluster endpoint WITHOUT authenticate with the cluster. Typically, you need to run your job using an IAM user who [has access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) to the cluster, and you set this up using secret file (actually it's the kubeconfig file).